# Import module in cookie-cutter flask

Tags: flask, cookiecutter

I'm using the template cookie-cutter flask.
I need to import sktime to use it in a python file, but it's not working and raise ModuleNotFoundError.

I tried to install a single version of python and install multiple times sktime, modify requirements.txt and package.json

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the Sktime docs?

https://www.sktime.net/en/stable/installation.html#id4

They have a section that goes into why you are receiving the ModuleNotFoundError:

> Module not found
> The most frequent reason for module not found errors is installing sktime with minimum dependencies and using an estimator which interfaces a package that has not been installed in the environment. To resolve this, install the missing package, or install sktime with maximum dependencies (see above).

This page will be able to give you everything you need to get the Framework working!